# How do you save a Git diff to a file in NetBeans?

Tags: git, netbeans, ide

I've cloned the repository for the project I'm on and opened it in NetBeans and made some changes and logged into the ReviewBoard site and now I need to upload a diff file for others on the project to see my changes. When I click in NetBeans' menu bar on Team->Diff, I can see a diff between my working copy and my Head, which is what I want to diff. I can see the textual version if I want as well by clicking on the textual tab in the diff window. What I don't see is where I can click to save this diff as a .diff file that ReviewBoard wants me to upload. An image of my screen as I graphically diff:
[image]

Comment: Don't know about netbeans - but it's very easy in command line, so I'll comment... Is viewing the diff in command line not an option? If you can get to the repo directory in command line, running `git diff > filename.diff` should output the diff into the file of specified for you :)

Comment: Yes, I've done it also from the command line (and this screenshot is of course a toy MWE and not my real project). The lead on the project has asked me to find out, if possible, how to do it from the IDE, as we have some people who are not really even coders doing UI stuff using SceneBuilder, which of course automatically changes .fxml files, as well as some specific stuff they know enough Java to do in .java files and want others on the project to be able to review. i.e., we have people who are cli-phobic :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to save a patch file by first opening the diff window in the IDE:

```
Team -> Diff -> Diff to Head
```

Then, when the diff is selected in the editor:

```
Team -> Patches -> Export Uncommited Changes
```

(NetBeans 8.2)